# Android. RxJava 2: Parallel multiple network calls

Tags: android, request, zip, rx-java2

I need make two parallel requests with RxJava. For this I use zip operator. Here is my code:

```
  public Disposable getBooksAndAuthors(String id, ReuqestCallback requestCallback) {
        return singleRequest(Single.zip(
                getBooks(id).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()),
                getAuthors(id).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()),
                (book, author) -> new ZipResponseWrapper(book, author).getResponse()), requestCallback);
    }

private <T extends NetworkResponse> Disposable singleRequest(Single<T> single, RequestCallback requestCallback) {
    return single.doOnSubscribe(d -> requestCallback.onStartRequest())
            .doOnSuccess(s -> requestCallback.onSuccess(s))
            .doOnError(ErrorConsumer.consume((t) -> requestCallback.onError(t)))
            .doFinally(() -> requestCallback.onFinish())
            .subscribe();
}
```

But I don’t understand how to receive response separately for each request. That is, I need to, if the answer came to the first request, immediately display the data received from this request and not wait for a response to the second request. And after the answer to the second request arrives, display the data received on the second request.This is necessary due to the fact that the second request fulfills a long time. Please help me.

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: @Kristy Welsh, I added some code

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can handle it with the responses for each function:

```
val disposable = Observable.zip(
    firstNetworkCall().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
    secondNetworkCall().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
    BiFunction{ 
      firstResonse: ResponseOneType, 
      secondResponse: ResponseTwoType -> 
      combineResult(firstResponse, secondResponse) }))
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe { it -> doSomethingWithIndividualResponse(it) }
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion (in Kotlin though):

```
val id = 0L
    
Observables.combineLatest(
        getBooks(id).startWith(emptyList<Book>()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(Schedulers.computation()),
        getAuthor(id).startWith(emptyList<Author>()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    ) { book: List<Book>, author: List<Author> ->
        Pair(book, author)
    }.skip(1)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { (books: List<Book>, authors: List<Author>) ->
            view.show(books)
            view.show(authors)
        }
```